# GET-style urls in Grails

Tags: url, grails, get

is there any way to create old-style GET urls in Grails. e.x. if I click a link or button, a want to open a page with url like **www.example.com/name=somename?surname=somesurname**.

P.S. sorry for my english

Comment: What about <g:link controller="whatever" action="something" params="[name: 'somename', surname: 'somesurname']">My link</g:link> doesn't work? That should create a GET style URL as you put it. Also using method="GET" on a <g:form> will use GET instead of the default POST. What problem are you facing using these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create URL/Links with query parameters, or GET style URLs as you call them, use the following:

```
<g:link controller="whatever" action="something" params="[name: 'somename', surname: 'somesurname']">My link</g:link>
```

and

```
<g:form name="MyFormName" controller="whatever" action="something" method="GET">
...
</g:form>
```